# Where can you find a Molten Core?

Tags: starbound

I need a Molten Core to craft a Metal Workbench, which presume will open up more crafting options to me. Where can I obtain one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fought the Penguin UFO last night. **You can get it from him**. A nice tactic is to use your universal tool and trap him with dirt, so he doesn't spawn penguins. Just hold him in place while you kill him.[image]

To spawn a Penguin UFO, Use a distress signal

Comment: oh, just a mention. if you fight the ufo this way, and it's gonna die, don't stand where I stood. it will fall and crush you

Comment: The tactic you are using doesn't work anymore since yesterdays patch I think because the patchnote sais:  Tweaked the UFO boss to make him smash blocks. (done)

Comment: Strange. Check the timestamp of my pc, was done at 11pm last night. He did smash a bit of my roof, but he didn't smash bricks above him

Answer (score 1):

As [link](http://starbounder.org/Molten_Core) says, it's rare drop of Penguin UFO. However, I haven't get that yet.